# Spring aop, unbound pointcut parameter

Tags: spring, aop

Im getting this error taht i dont really understand:

```
unbound pointcut parameter auditable
```

following code:

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    @Before(value = "@annotation(Action)")
    public void audit(JoinPoint joinPoint, Action auditable) {
        System.out.println(auditable);
    }
}

 @Action(ActionType.FAST)
    public static void resolveFast(String name){
        System.out.println(name);
    }

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Action {

    ActionType value();
    boolean withArgs() default false;
}

public enum ActionType {
    FAST, SLOW
}
```

the problem occurs on @Before annotation, these are my first steps in aop...

Answer (score 14):

In this statement:

```java
 @Before(value = "@annotation(Action)")
```

You should replace `Action` with `auditable`.

Comment: Please mention why you're suggesting that fix! thanks!

Comment: Spring and its quirks. The aspect interface name will work if the aspect has no parameters, but should be changed to parameter name if aspect has parameters

Answer (score 10):

change the code like this:

```
    @Before(value = "@annotation(auditable)")
    public void audit(JoinPoint joinPoint, Action auditable) {
        System.out.println(auditable);
    }
```

You see the different??

Right, `@annotation`'s parameter should be **`auditable`**!!!

Ok, right now, I just spent almost 2 hour to debug...

Just this. I feel waste my life, but I really hope save yours...

I still feel bad...

Answer (score 2):

try reference code

```
@Before("execution(public String com.captaindebug.audit.controller.*Controller.*(..)) && @annotation(auditAnnotation)")
    public void auditScreen(JoinPoint joinPoint,Audit auditAnnotation) {...}
```